# How to make a linked list sorted?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Write a java method in your Linked List Project to perform the sorted insertion in your Linked List. Sorted insertion is one in which, whenever you insert a new element, it is inserted on its sorted location. but I'm not getting the output here is my code.

```
{
  public void insertSorted(int data) 
{
    
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    if(head == null || head.Data > data) 
    {
        temp.next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    Node head2 = head;
    while(head2.next != null && head2.next.Data < data) 
    {
        head2 = head2.next;
    }
    temp.next = head.next;
    head.next = temp;
}

public void Display() 
{
    Node t = head;
    while(t != null)
    {
        System.out.print(t.Data+" -> ");
        t = t.next;
    }
    System.out.println("NULL");
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you rhink condition `(curr.Data * 1) != 0` helps you define the odd  number better than old-fashioned modulo by 2 `curr.Data % 2 != 0`?  Is it just a typo?

Comment: Hello, Alex Rudenko I edited my question can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one it will work as you expected ->

```
 public void seprator1(Node curr) {
    if (curr == null || curr.next == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node Even, EvenTail, oddStartingNode, oddEndNode;

    Even = EvenTail = oddStartingNode = oddEndNode = null;

    while (curr != null) {
        if (curr.data % 2 == 0) {
            if (Even == null) {
                Even = curr;
                EvenTail = Even;
            } else {
                EvenTail.next = curr;
                EvenTail = EvenTail.next;
            }
        } else {
            if (oddStartingNode == null) {
                oddStartingNode = curr;
                oddEndNode = oddStartingNode;
            } else {
                oddEndNode.next = curr;
                oddEndNode = oddEndNode.next;
            }
        }

        curr = curr.next;
    }

    displayNode(Even);
    System.out.println();
    displayNode(oddStartingNode);

}

private void displayNode(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(node.data+" ");
    displayNode(node.next);
}
```

Comment: How we will display these lists?

Comment: Hello, murari99732 I edited my question can you help me?

Comment: You can take above code it will print. But in your solution you are returning int instead return node.

Comment: can you code the display method for the above code?

Comment: https://github.com/murari99732/solutionleetcode-adventofcode/blob/master/PracticeAlgo/src/LinkedListApplication.java  you can check it here. I have coded it here.